# Same-type constraint type 'τ_0_0.AssociatedType' does not conform to required protocol 'ProtocolName'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift-protocols

I have the following code:

```
protocol ResourceFetchable {

associatedtype ResourceType: Resource

/**
 Fetches a resource using the provided service

 - parameter resource: The resource to fetch
 - parameter service:  The service to be used for fetching the resource
 */
func fetch<Service: ResourceService>(resource: ResourceType, usingService service: Service) where Service.ResourceType == ResourceType

}
```

The `ResourceFetchable` uses `ResourceService` which goes like so -

```
protocol ResourceService {

associatedtype ResourceType: Resource

/**
 Fetch a resource

 - parameter resource:   The resource to fetch
 - parameter completion: A completion handler called with a Result type of the fetching computation
 */

func fetch(resource: ResourceType, completion: @escaping (Result<ResourceType.Model>) -> Void)

}
```

And `Resource` is a simple protocol which goes like -

```
public protocol Resource {
associatedtype Model
}
```

and `Result` is defined as -

```
public enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(Error)
}
```

Everything looks fine, but the compiler throws this error -

> Same-type constraint type 'τ_0_0.ResourceType' does not conform to
>   required protocol 'Resource'

I've narrowed it down to the protocol constraint `where` clause in `ResourceFetchable`'s `fetch` method

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've got a few syntax errors there -- `protocol ResourceFetchable:`, missing paren at end of `func fetch` in `ResourceService` are the ones I notice.

Comment: @BallpointBen @Hamish Added the definition for `Result`. And thanks for pointing the typo. I had inherited from some protocol which is not relevant to this question.

Comment: @RamsundarShandilya The code you've posted compiles fine me – have you verified that this minimal example reproduces your problem? If so, you may want to try cleaning you build folder.

Comment: Yes, I did try pasting the snippet in Playgrounds file & it works fine. It's only in the actual project where I face this issue. Weird!

Comment: The error message refers to `ResourceService`'s `ResourceType` btw.

Comment: No solution sorry, but I am seeing the same problem too with Xcode 8.2b2 (Radar 29359068).